# Ansible: (unexpected) hostvars items always overwritten by values for last host in group during task loop

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x, cisco, ansible-inventory

I am attempting to write an Ansible playbook that runs a handful of tasks to configure Cisco IOS routers. Some of these tasks need to loop over list variables that are defined at the host variables file level. For example, given one or more interfaces, configure x on that interface. Or, given one or more fvrfs, configure nameservers for each fvrf. The number of interfaces and fvrfs are dynamic. There are multiple tasks that have dynamic list values like this within the playbook role.

The problem that I am running into is that host variables with unique values for each router are always being set to the values defined for the last router in the group. This is happening for variables that are a string and variables that are a list of strings. In other words, the hostvars of the routers preceding the last router in the inventory group are always being overwritten by the hostvars defined for the last router.

Ansible Runtime:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.7.0
  config file = /opt/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/<redacted>/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/<redacted>/mypython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/<redacted>/mypython/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, Oct 22 2018, 15:22:25) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)]
(A) (mypython) <redacted>@<redacted_hostname> /opt/ansible
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.7.0
  config file = /opt/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/<redacted>/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/<redacted>/mypython/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/<redacted>/mypython/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, Oct 22 2018, 15:22:25) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)]
```

Directory structure:

```
+-- ansible.cfg
+-- inventory
|   +-- lab-g2
|   |   +-- group_vars
|   |   |   +-- lab-g2-crs-2900
|   |   |       +-- host_vars
|   |   |       |   +-- 10.74.0.71.yml
|   |   |       |   +-- 10.74.0.73.yml
|   |   |       +-- vars
|   |   +-- inventory
+-- library
+-- playbooks
|   +-- roles -> /opt/ansible/roles
|   +-- set-nameservers.yml
+-- README.md
+-- roles
|    +-- set-nameservers
    |   +-- tasks
    |       +-- main.yml
```

playbook.yml:

```
---

- name: CONFIGURE NAMESERVERS ON ROUTER
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  connection: network_cli

  roles:
    - set-nameservers
```

Inventory file:

```
[lab-g2-crs-2900]
10.74.0.71
10.74.0.73

[all:children]
lab-g2-crs-2900
```

Group variables file:

```
---

ansible_connection: network_cli
ansible_network_os: ios
```

Host variable files:

10.74.0.71.yml:

```
fvrf: ["WAN1", "WAN2"]
umbrella_out: ["GigabitEthernet0/0"]
```

10.74.0.73.yml:

```
fvrf: ["WAN3", "WAN4"]
umbrella_out: ["GigabitEthernet0/1"]
```

roles/set-nameservers/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: CONFIGURE NAMESERVERS
  ios_config:
    lines:
      - "ip name-server vrf {{ item }} 208.67.220.220 208.67.222.222"
  with_items: "{{ fvrf }}"

- name: DEBUG
  debug:
    msg: "fvrf name is {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ fvrf }}"

- name: CONFIGURE UMBRELLA OUTBOUND INTERFACE
  ios_config:
    lines:
      - "description Outbound umbrella interface"
    parents: interface {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ umbrella_out }}"

- name: DEBUG
  debug:
    msg: "Outbound Umbrella interface is {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ umbrella_out }}"
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
PLAY [CONFIGURE NAMESERVERS ON ROUTER] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set-nameservers : CONFIGURE NAMESERVERS] *******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN3)
changed: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN1)
changed: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN4)
changed: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN2)

TASK [set-nameservers : DEBUG] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN3) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN1"
}
ok: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN4) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN2"
}
ok: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN3) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN3"
}
ok: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN4) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN4"
}

TASK [set-nameservers : CONFIGURE UMBRELLA OUTBOUND INTERFACE] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.74.0.73] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/0)
changed: [10.74.0.71] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1)

TASK [set-nameservers : DEBUG] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.74.0.71] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1) => {
    "msg": "Outbound Umbrella interface is GigabitEthernet0/0"
}
ok: [10.74.0.73] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1) => {
    "msg": "Outbound Umbrella interface is GigabitEthernet0/1"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.74.0.71                : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
10.74.0.73                : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**ACTUAL RESULT**

```
PLAY [CONFIGURE NAMESERVERS ON ROUTER] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set-nameservers : CONFIGURE NAMESERVERS] *******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN3)
changed: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN3)
changed: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN4)
changed: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN4)

TASK [set-nameservers : DEBUG] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN3) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN3"
}
ok: [10.74.0.71] => (item=WAN4) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN4"
}
ok: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN3) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN3"
}
ok: [10.74.0.73] => (item=WAN4) => {
    "msg": "fvrf name is WAN4"
}

TASK [set-nameservers : CONFIGURE UMBRELLA OUTBOUND INTERFACE] ***************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.74.0.73] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1)
changed: [10.74.0.71] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1)

TASK [set-nameservers : DEBUG] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.74.0.71] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1) => {
    "msg": "Outbound Umbrella interface is GigabitEthernet0/1"
}
ok: [10.74.0.73] => (item=GigabitEthernet0/1) => {
    "msg": "Outbound Umbrella interface is GigabitEthernet0/1"
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.74.0.71                : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
10.74.0.73                : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

As you can see from the output result, the variables from the host file for 10.74.0.73 are being used for both hosts, even though 10.74.0.71 has its own unique variable values defined in a separate file. In a separate playbook with the same structure and 16 routers, it was showing the same behavior... using the hostvars of the last router in the group for all 16 routers (yikes!)

I've been searching the web for a few hours and have looked through the Ansible docs and a lot of discussion here pertaining to loops, variables, and variable precedence. I haven't figured out what the issue is. I think the most likely culprit is that I am misunderstanding how the `with_items` operation works, but I don't know how to modify the tasks to ensure the desired result where each host has unique variable lists. Could this possibly be bug behavior?

Any assistance with this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Geoff, welcome to SO! What's going on with `ansible 2.7.0.dev0`? Did you build ansible from git? Are you able to reproduce this behavior with a released version?

Comment: Matt, I noticed that issue as well when I was troubleshooting and went through the process of setting up a fresh Python virtualenv with the stable release of 2.7. I'm getting the same results, however. I updated the runtime information in my original post. All of the result output was generated with the stable release version, I just neglected to update the runtime information with the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the directory output, that was the key. It's not the `with_items` that's causing you the problems, it's the nested `host_vars` within `group_vars`.

If you pull the `host_vars` up out of the `group_vars` directory, it will start to behave sanely again. I haven't dug into the assignment rules to find out *exactly* at which point it is being superseded, but the tl;dr is that the top bucket is *not* host specific, even though the bottom bucket *is*, thus:

```
hostvars["10.74.0.71"] = # the correct thing 
vars["lab-g2-crs-2900"] = {}
for h in ["10.74.0.71", ...etc...]:
   vars["lab-g2-crs-2900"].update(hostvars[h])
# and now the value in the group_vars "masks off" the host-specific one
# because they appear to be applied in reverse-depth-first order
```

You can confirm for yourself without running the entire playbook just using `ansible-inventory --list` and looking at the `hostvars` in `_meta`

Comment: That was the culprit! I moved the host_vars directory up to the inventory/lab-g2 directory and that resolved the problem. Now getting the expected results. Thank you very much for the help Matt! :)